# Responsive background image without media queries

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, background-image, responsiveness, responsive-images

I need some guidance into making a responsive background image for an admin page without using media queries. The background image needs to respond to the browser window without stretching.

Similar to this [example page](https://login.salesforce.com)

I using bootstrap 3.3.6 to build this page. The admin login page is divided as a split screen.

- Left hand side is login area
- Right hand side is a background image with text content on top. 
  [image: login page]

[http://www.r1.jxt.com.au/Admin/login.aspx?ReturnURL=~%2fadmin%2fdefault.aspx](http://www.r1.jxt.com.au/Admin/login.aspx?ReturnURL=~%2Fadmin%2Fdefault.aspx)

I need all the guidance I can get to going about making this happen. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `.bg-image` class with following:

```
.bg-image {
    background: url(../img/bg-image-md.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/BKdgKP

```
.bg-image{
background-image: url(http://images.jxt.net.au/jxt-admin/img/bg-image-lg.jpg);
background-size:cover;
background-position:50% 0 ;
}
```

Use the background-size property with the value of either cover or contain, and position the background image as required.

[More info on the background-size property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/)